# Python: Creating a new list out of a range of indices from another list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

I have a list: `A = [6, 4, 3, 5, 2, 1]` and I want to create a new list: `B = []` where B is populated by the elements from A in range of indices 0 ---> 0 + some variable.

(that is, given a range of indices in A, how can I copy the elements over that range into a new list B?)

Comment: `B = A[:endingIndex]`

Comment: So simple! Thank you NightShadeQueen

Comment: See:  [Explain Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)